# User search and sign-in blocked

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

When doing a user search the results include users with no licenses and sign-in blocked. Is it possible to exclude these users from the results?

WebApp permissions are "User.Read" and "User.ReadBasic.All".

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following filter will limit the accounts returned.

```
?$filter=accountEnabled eq true
```

What is confusing is that "User.ReadBasic.All" only allows certain properties to be returned (display name, first, last name, photo, email address), but you can still filter on other properties.